# glDrawArrays throws 1282 error and does not draw anything

Tags: c++, opengl

I checked this question.

[gldrawarrays does not draw anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855594/gldrawarrays-does-not-draw-anything) => not applicable because I am using shaders.

My code goes as follows:

```cpp
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

This initialises a vao first.

```cpp
GLuint vertexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1,&vertexBuffer);


float vertices[]={
  -0.5f,-0.5f,
  0.0f,0.0f,
  0.5f,0.5f
};

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Binds the buffer and adds the data

```cpp
const char* vertexSource = reader("./shaders/chapter-one.vert").c_str();
GLuint vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
glCompileShader(vShader);
GLint vStatus;
glGetShaderiv(vShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vStatus);
if(vStatus!=GL_TRUE){
  printf("Vertex Shader not Compiled\n");
}

char vBuffer[512];
glGetShaderInfoLog(vShader, 512, NULL, vBuffer);
cout<<vBuffer;


const char* fragmentSource = reader("./shaders/chapter-one.frag").c_str();
GLuint fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
glCompileShader(fShader);
GLint fStatus;
glGetShaderiv(fShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &fStatus);
if(fStatus!=GL_TRUE){
  printf("Fragment Shader not compiled");
}

char fBuffer[512];
glGetShaderInfoLog(fShader, 512, NULL, fBuffer);
cout << fBuffer;

GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vShader);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fShader);
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
```

Adds the shader and creates a program. I also retrieve errors and logs for each step which are empty currently. So no errors compiling or creating shaders and program.

```cpp
GLuint posLoc = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "p");
printf("%i\n", posLoc);
glVertexAttribPointer(posLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posLoc);
```

Gets the attribute from shader to feed the data to.

```cpp
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 3); // => This part does not work
```

Upon calling `glGetError()` after `glDrawArrays` I get 1282 error. I know `glDrawArrays` is causing this error as just before `glDrawArrays` I tried calling `glGetErrors()` and there wer no errors.
I think the problem is in setup somewhere

Any Suggestions??

Edit: I tried changing my code according to Rabbid76's suggestion and I am still getting the same error.
I checked the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) and I think this is the applicable case.

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if a non-zero buffer object name is bound to an enabled array and the buffer object's data store is currently mapped.

What does it mean in this situation and what changes should I make?

Full code [here](https://github.com/git-somenumber/opengl-learn/blob/chapter-1/src/chapter-1.cpp)

Yes, I got took both my code and example code side by side and changed anything that seemed inconsistent. I changed both `glDrawElements` and had to adjust my `glVertexAttribPointer`. Stupid mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) in your code. There is just a [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) and that will cause an error, because you have not specified any [Index buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers).
Furthermore, the type argument to [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) has to be the type of the indices. The allowed types are `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`.

Remove `glDrawElements` and use `glDrawArrays` to solve the issue:

<s>`glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0);`</s>

```cpp
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

---

Furthermore the [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) and the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) have to be bound, before invoking [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml). `glVertexAttribPointer` associates the buffer which is currently bound to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` to the specified attribute (index) and states the specification in the state vector of the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer); 
glVertexAttribPointer(posLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```